# How to match key/value groups with regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

Provided the following string:

```
@NAMEONE=any@character@OTHERNAME=any @ character@THIRDNAME=even new lines
are possible
```

How can we match the full name/value pairs like `@NAMEONE=any@character`?

I am stuck with this regex `(@(?:NAMEONE|OTHERNAME|THIRDNAME)=.+?)+` as it only matches `@NAMEONE=a`, `@OTHERNAME=a` etc. Using Java.

Comment: You have not given the regex an option to stop .So it stops on first instance as it is non greedy

Comment: @anubhava yes the value can contain `@`

Comment: I have posted shorter and more generic version. Please check below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would match any character but not of `@` and also `@` only if the preceding and following character of `@` is a non-word character.

```
"@(?:NAMEONE|OTHERNAME|THIRDNAME)=(?:\\B@\\B|[^@])*"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yP9gA5/2)

or

```
"(?s)@(?:NAMEONE|OTHERNAME|THIRDNAME)=.*?(?=@(?:NAMEONE|OTHERNAME|THIRDNAME)=|$)"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yP9gA5/5)

Comment: Almost there! It fails for @NAMEONE=any@character

Comment: The second does the job. A question: what does the (?s) stands for? I removed it and it still works.

Comment: `(?s)` called dotall modifier which makes dot present in the regex to match also line breaks. If you removed that, it won't match the value part which does have newline character.

Comment: That makes sense. The reason it worked without it, is because I set the `Pattern.DOTALL` when compiling the pattern in Java. With the `(?s)` is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit shorter version based on the uperrcase name for variables:

> (@[A-Z]+=.+?)(?=@[A-Z]+=|$)

**Explanation:**
`@[A-Z]+=` matches the variable name and the `=` sign 
`.+?`     laziely matches any character
`(?=@[A-Z]+=|$)` positive look-ahead for variable name or end of string

**Java code:**

```
public static void test()
{
  String str = "@NAMEONE=any @ character@OTHERNAME=any @ character@THIRDNAME=even";
  Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(@[A-Z]+=.+?)(?=@[A-Z]+=|$)").matcher(str);
  while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
  }
}
```

prints

```
@NAMEONE=any @ character
@OTHERNAME=any @ character
@THIRDNAME=eve
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sY3oO6/3)